# Was Zephyr-1 really S.H.I.E.L.D.'s first spaceship? (Or, did S.H.I.E.L.D. have a space program prior to 2018?)

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spaceship, agents-of-shield

In Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D. Season 5 Episode 20, "The One Who Saves Us All", Agent Alphonso "Mack" Mackenzie modifies Zephyr-1 to be spaceworthy. Leo Fitz then remarks, "Guess who built S.H.I.E.L.D.'s first spaceship?" This line got me wondering... was it S.H.I.E.L.D.'s first spaceship in the MCU or live-action shows? I know Fury is seen in space at the end of *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, but that *is* after that episode, by a year or so. **Did S.H.I.E.L.D. have spaceships or a space program prior to Zephyr-1?**

Comment: AoS season 5 and Far From Home are not in the same continuity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 1995, a jointly S.H.I.E.L.D.-owned Quadjet was modified by Skrulls to be space-worthy, as seen in *Captain Marvel.*

[image]

Comment: Earlier in the timeline of the film, Dr. Lawson's jet that was modified with the Space Stone in the engine was implied to be space-worthy, and predates this by a couple years presumably?  Not sure if they said the year specifically.  (She was able to visit the Skrull space station in orbit - perhaps was even involved in building it?  Or is that Skrull construction?  Not sure on that.  So anyhow, she must've had some means to get her there, and that was years before Carol lost her memory and joined the Kree, so well before this.)

Comment: Ah, that does it... I'm not too keen on that movie, so I've only seen it once, which explains why I didn't remember